# IntelliJIDEA WELD-001408 exception when trying to deploy javaEE maven packed application on glassfish

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish, dependencies

Im using JavaEE 7, Glassfish 4, Maven 3.2.1.

I have read several posts where users get exact error, which represents wide area of actual problems, as stated here: [CDI Inject fails on maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin -- org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107858/cdi-inject-fails-on-maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin-org-jboss-weld-exceptions)

So, how can I determine whats the actual problem? All annotations seem to be correct, as same code works for my teammates on their own machines...

For example for project manager, I have interface like:

```
@Local
public interface ProjectManager { some mtehods...}
```

then I have implementation of it like:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "projectManager")
public class ProjectManagerEJB implements ProjectManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "scrumkin_PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private GroupManager gm;

    @Override
    public void someMethod(...);

    some other methods...
}
```

And the RESTful:

```
@Path("project")
@Stateless
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ProjectService {

    @Inject
    private UserManager um;
    @Inject
    private ProjectManager pm;

    @POST
    public void createProject(ProjectJSON project, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {...} 

    some other methods...
}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem was, I imported project on which I was working on with eclipse, so now I pulled repository into another location and I was able to deploy with IntelliJIDEA (is it possible to use same location of project for Eclipse and IntelliJIDEA (as in, import project in IntelliJIDEA without Eclipse settings (settings files), because they are causing problems)?).

But now, calls to RESTful service are not working, this is what glassfish log looks like after deploying (the warnings part):

```
[2014-04-11T23:48:57.922+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252937922] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:57.923+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252937923] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.643+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938643] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registering the Jersey servlet application, named com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication, at the servlet mapping /*, with the Application class of the same name.]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.698+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938698] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [scrumkin-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT#scrumkin-rs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] at [/api]]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.729+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938729] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.730+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938730] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.731+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938731] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.731+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938731] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.732+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938732] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.733+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938733] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.734+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938734] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.734+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938734] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.735+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938735] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.736+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938736] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.736+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938736] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.737+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938737] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.738+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938738] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.739+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938739] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.LoginService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.LoginService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.739+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938739] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.SprintService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.740+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938740] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserStoryService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.741+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938741] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.741+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938741] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.UserService, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.UserService]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.742+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-UTIL-00035] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938742] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to load class com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:58.777+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252938777] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [scrumkin-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT#scrumkin-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] at [/]]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:59.125+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1397252939125] [levelValue: 800] [[
  scrumkin-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT was successfully deployed in 9.668 milliseconds.]]

[2014-04-11T23:48:59.779+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1397252939779] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /]]
```

And when I try to call some valid RESTful path (a GET method), I get:

```
[2014-04-12T00:05:17.679+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1397253917679] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...]]

[2014-04-12T00:05:17.853+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1397253917853] [levelValue: 800] [[
  The Jersey EJB interceptor is bound. JAX-RS EJB integration support is enabled.]]

[2014-04-12T00:05:18.934+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [ejb.system_exception] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1397253918934] [levelValue: 900] [[
  EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ProjectService, method: public com.scrumkin.rs.json.ProjectJSON com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService.getProject(int)]]

[2014-04-12T00:05:18.934+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1397253918934] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy219.getProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.scrumkin.rs.__EJB31_Generated__ProjectService__Intf____Bean__.getProject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService.getProject(ProjectService.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 54 more
]]

[2014-04-12T00:05:18.977+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1397253918977] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.scrumkin.rs.RESTApplication threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.scrumkin.rs.ProjectService.getProject(ProjectService.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy219.getProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.scrumkin.rs.__EJB31_Generated__ProjectService__Intf____Bean__.getProject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

Comment: What are you trying to inject? If you post some code it could help.

Comment: did you put beans.xml as it is required?

Comment: I thought about it, but how come my teammates dont need it? Anyways, where exactly do I need to put it in what should its content be like? The project is divided into these sections/maps: ejb, api, jpa, web, rs (for services), ear.

Comment: That sounds wierd. As you can read here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html - it is required by specification. I am not sure how it is possible your collegues do not need it. However it is empty in simple cases. You can find what 'empty' means here https://code.google.com/p/jee6-cdi/wiki/DependencyInjectionAnIntroductoryTutorial_Part1#Step_1:_Create_an_empty_bean.xml_file_under_META-INF_resource_fo

Comment: so that should be basically it? will try later today and let you know the outcome

Comment: JavaEE 7 doesn't need beans.xml. Anyways I found the solution, got new problems, check edit above.

Comment: Oh, EE7. Did not realise it is ee7. My bad. About your exception: it is NPE in your ProjectService, but the information you provided is not enough to analize it